# LINK : fatal error LNK1104 in cmake project when using relative paths for IMPORTED_IMPLIB and IMPORTED_LOCATION

Tags: c, cmake, dll, shared-libraries, import-libraries

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(GarbageCollector C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

add_library(collections SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(collections PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB "lib/Release/Collections.lib"
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "bin/Debug/Collections.dll")
add_executable(gc ./main.c)

target_link_libraries(gc collections)
```

LINK : fatal error LNK1104. says that cant open Collections.lib

when i try to cmake --build build i get LINK : fatal error LNK1104.

Comment: Properties `IMPORTED_IMPLIB` and `IMPORTED_LOCATION` should contain **absolute** paths. Use `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` for refer to the directory where `CMakeLists.txt` resides.

Answer (score 0):

Both [`IMPORTED_IMPLIB`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_IMPLIB.html) and [`IMPORTED_LOCATION`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_LOCATION.html) require full (absolute) paths.

If you want to anchor the paths you have to something, see the following variables and use whichever one suits the needs in your context:

- [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html)
- [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html)
- [`<PROJECT-NAME>_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PROJECT-NAME_SOURCE_DIR.html)
- [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html)
- [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html)

Ex.

```
set_target_properties(collections PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/Release/Collections.lib"
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/Debug/Collections.dll"
)
```